# require подключение модуля mongo(node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, cordova

вообщем такой код:

```
function hello() {
                var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
        var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbbook';
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
          assert.equal(null, err);
          alert("Connected correctly to server");

          db.close();
        });
    }
```

После загрузки браузер ругается,

```
Module name "mongodb" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

**добавляю в свой код '[]'** далее он пишет такие же ошибки вглубь по всем файлам монги, тоесть их море и менять всё require(['']) вручную не вариант. Уверен что где то что то упустил - надеюсь на помощь.

п.с.: библиотека require.js подключена - проект на js - css - html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От вас просят использовать асинхронную форму записи:

```
require(['mongodb'], function (mongodb) {
    // Здесь можно использовать mongodb
});
```

Если сообщение ошибки содержит "Use require([])", то вы не можете использовать форму `require('foo')`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, тоесть если я понял правильно, то мне переписывать все js файлы входящие в библиотеку монго самостотельно в такой форме, если вылетает такая ошибка?

Comment: @AlexeyAl Не понял, что вы собрались переписывать, но код на верхнем уровне должен быть таким, асинхронным. Код, который вы вызываете внутри этого колбэка, уже может ипользовать `require('foo')`, если require и foo указаны в зависимостях. См. http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

Comment: изменил на код асинхронный:  `require(['lib/mongo_client'], function (mongodb) {
             MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbbook', function(err, db) {
             db.close();
             });
        });`

браузер далее даёт ошибку:
`Module name "lib/url_parser" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

Comment: тоесть получается нужно перекопать все файлы js и сделать их так сказать - асинхронными? Потому что браузер выдает ошибки всё в глуб и глубь файлов - правлю я url_parser  он просит править events.js и тд.

Comment: @AlexeyAl Я не пойму: вы написали десятки файлов с кодом, в каждом по тысяче строк, и ни разу не попробовали запустить? Как у вас раньше работало-то?

Comment: Я не писал же этот код, я просто установил пакет mongojs в приложение и хочу из своего уже файла js сделать запрос ,по аналогии как ранее работал с python и устанавливал  pymongo в окружение, писал в коде просто import pymongo и далее писал свой запрос на питоне к бд. Тут же он загрузил главный js файл монги, который в свою очередь включает в себя require на разветвления. Возможно нужно всё мне пересмотреть.